# Can't get ButterKnife to work with Android Studio

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, butterknife

I've searched and tried many attempts to resolve errors and nothing so far works.  My code ran fine until I decided to use Butter Knife. I have updated my gradle files as such:

app.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
apply plugin: 'com.jakewharton.butterknife'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    buildToolsVersion '28.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.udacity.sandwichclub"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

repositories {
    google()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0'

    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:28.0.0'

    //butterknife
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
}
```

Project gradle file:

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0'
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:10.0.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

If I leave as above, I get this error:

> ERROR: Android Gradle plugin 3.3.0 must not be applied to project
>   '/Users/verityt/Documents/Android/NanoDegree2018/SandwichClub/app'
>   since version 3.3.0 was already applied to this project Open File

I tried commenting out one of the apply plugin listed on Jake Wharton's Butter Knife instructions

> //apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

And I get this error:

> More than one file was found with OS independent path
>   'META-INF/androidx.core_core.version'

Any help please?

Comment: is it a library or application?
if its a library then why apply plugin: 'com.android.application'?

Comment: Why don't you use kotlin extension plugin? It provides you the direct access to all the views and viewgroups. Have a look at this https://antonioleiva.com/kotlin-android-extensions/

Answer (score 0):

**Few notes**

Use `com.android.library` when importing it in a library/module.

Also, do not apply the plugin alongside `com.android.application`.

**What you can do**

```
android {
     packagingOptions {
         exclude 'META-INF/androidx.core_core.version'
     }
}
```

**Important note**

During such dependency updates, it's good to read first their release notes and the possible side effects

Eg.

- https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md
- https://developer.android.com/jetpack/docs/release-notes

Answer (score 0):

change to 
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:8.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:8.0.0'

That's ok to me.